# Count frequency of n-gram in text using r

Tags: r, text, n-gram

**I am using R to read the text. A passage consists of 100 sentences,then it is put in a list, the list is like:**

```
[[1]]

[1] "WigWagCo: For #TBT here's a video of Travis McCollum (Co-Founder and COO of WigWag) at #SXSW2016

[[2]]

[1] "chrisreedfilm: RT @hammertonail: #SXSW2016 doc THE SEER: A PORTRAIT OF WENDELL BERRY gets reviewed by @chrisreedfilm 

[[3]]

[1] "iamscottrandell: RT @therevue: Take a jaunt down #MemoriesofSXSW &amp; read the stories of @JRNelsonMusic @thegillsmusic &amp; @TheBlancosMusic 
...
...

[[99]]

[1] "SunPowerTalent: SunPower #Clerical #Job: Supply Chain Intern (#Austin, TX) 

[[100]]

[1] "SunPowerTalent: #Finance #Job alert: General Ledger Accountant | SunPower
```

**Every object in the list is a "sentence" from a same text.
How can I count frequency of all 3-gram in this text and know which sentence is each 3-gram from?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the R package `textcat` (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=textcat) for this. If your list of 100 sentences is called `x` you simply do:

```
library("textcat")
n3gram <- textcat_profile_db(x, n = 3)
```

This is then a list of 100 elements (corresponding to the original sentences) containing the 3-grams ordered by frequency. See `?textcat_profile_db` for more details and examples.